# Convert text files into Excel workbooks and call a macro on another module

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to convert text files into Excel workbooks, open them, and then call a macro on another module (Call DataCleanBehfMRI). Then do the same thing, looping through text files in other subfolders.

Folder structure:

```
V:\Behavioral\Twin_behaviorTry\19510196-1\WorkingMemory.txt

V:\Behavioral\Twin_behaviorTry\19510197-1\WorkingMemory.txt
```

etc.

So each "WorkingMemory.txt" file contains data to run Macros on, for each subject (19510196-1,19510197-1, etc.).

I tried to loop through individual files, within multiple folders and tried to adapt it with text files but it just skips the code from `Workbooks.OpenText filename:=folderPath & filename, _` to `end if`.

```
Sub LoopSubfoldersAndFiles()

Dim foo As Object
Dim folder As Object
Dim subfolders As Object
Dim MyFile As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim CurrFile As Object

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End With

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set folder = fso.GetFolder("V:\Behavioral\Twin_behaviorTry\")
Set subfolders = folder.subfolders
MyFile = "*.txt"

For Each subfolders In subfolders

    Set CurrFile = subfolders.Files

    For Each CurrFile In CurrFile

        If CurrFile.Name = MyFile Then

            Workbooks.OpenText filename:=folderPath & filename, _
              Origin:=xlMSDOS, StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:= _
              xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=True, Semicolon:=False, _
              Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), _
              Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

            Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

            'Call a subroutine here to operate on the just-opened workbook
            Call DataCleanBehfMRI
            'close open work book

            wb.Close SaveChanges:=False

            filename = Dir
        End If
    Next

Next

Set fso = Nothing
Set folder = Nothing
Set subfolders = Nothing

With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Change `If CurrFile.Name = MyFile Then` to `If  Right(CurrFile.Name , 4) = ".txt" Then`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the line:

```
If CurrFile.Name = MyFile Then
```

Try using the line:

```
If Dir(MyFile) = CurrFile.Name Then
```

And it should work, hopefully.

Comment: Thank you Vikram for your quick reply. It doesn't change anything tho, still skips the code from "Workbooks.OpenText filename:=folderPath & filename, _" to "end if".  Cheers

Comment: Do you use 'Option Explicit' at the top of the module? If you do, you will find 'fso' is misspelled as 'foo" and that the variable 'FolderPath' is not defined, nor is 'filename'! Sorry, that's about I could reach in this!! :-)

Comment: I didn't know about 'Option Explicit', thanks! Sorry about the "foo" it's an autocorrection that happened after I copied the code to this forum. Just defined FolderPath, still doesn't change anything.

Comment: If you could send me a sample excel workbook with sample data, maybe I could work out a solution for you, because without live data, it is difficult to explain. I will be using comments in the VBA Code to help you understand better. Warmest Regards, Vikram Shankar Mathur

Answer (score 0):

I see at least 3 issues with your code.

- The first was already mentioned in  Mikku's comment and Vikram's answer:  `If CurrFile.Name = MyFile Then` will never be true as you are comparing a filename (eg `WorkingMemory.txt` with the string `*.txt`. You can correct this by using the `Right`-Function to compare only the rightmost 4 chararacters. As an alternative you could use the `like`-operator: `If CurrFile.Name like MyFile Then` which will consider the wildcard - character. I would give the advice to use the `lcase`-function so you can catch also a file `WorkingMemory.TXT`:

  ```
  If lcase(CurrFile.Name) like "*.txt" Then
  ```
- The second thing is that you shouldn't use the same variables for collections (`subfolders`, `CurrFile`) and the variables you use to loop over this collection using `For Each`. Although it seems to work in this case, there is no guarantee. In your case, no need to save the collection into an intermediate variable, use a logic like `For Each subfolder in folder.subfolders` and `For Each currFile in subfolder.Files`.
- The third thing is that in `Workbook.Open`, you are using a undeclared variable `folderPath`, so the filename will be wrong (and the open will fail). Advice: Put `Option Explicit` at the top of your module, this enforces that all variables needs to be declared and you catch such errors much easier. I would suggest to use an intermediate variable to create the full filename before you open it.

Some other things to mention:

- `Workbook.Open` is a *function* that returns the opened workbook, so you can assign the result directly to your `wb`-variable.
- Pass the Workbook-Variable as parameter to `DataCleanBehfMRI`-routine so that this routine knows which workbook is should handle.

  ```
  Sub DataCleanBehfMRI(wb as Workbook)
  ```
- The `Dir`-command at the end of your inner loop is useless, it looks like it is a relict from earlier attempts.

So your code could look like this:

```
Const baseFolder = "V:\Behavioral\Twin_behaviorTry\"

Set folder = fso.GetFolder("V:\Behavioral\Twin_behaviorTry\")
Dim subfolder as object
For Each subfolder In folder.subfolders
    For Each currFile In subfolder.Files
        If lcase(currFile.Name) like "*.txt" then
            dim fullFileNameas string
            fullFileName=  baseFolder & subFolder.Name & currFile.Name
            Debug.Print "I will open now " & fullFileName
            set wb = Workbooks.OpenText(filename:=fullFileName... )
            DataCleanBehfMRI wb
       End If
    Next currFile 
Next subFolder
```

If the routine still doesn't do what you expect it to do, you should use the debugger and step thru your code and see what happens.